# In a triangle, does an angle bisector necessarily bisect the opposite side?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry, plane-geometry

Have a look at the triangle and tell me if $AD=DB$:[image]

Comment: Only if CD is a perpendicular down to AB

Comment: No.  Why should it be?

Comment: Say $a = 3$ and $b=4$. Now, let $a=3$ and $b=5$. Is $AB$ the same measurement on each of both occasions? The same applies if $a=b=3$. But... what if we consider a more general case, say $a=b$?

Answer (score 2):

I can understand your thinking: equal things (angles) should make equal things (lines).

But angles don't project linearly.  (Just think of a shadow across a slanted wall).  So this doesn't hold.

=====

Alternative but similar question (I'm just switching that the lines *are* equal but asking if the angles are?)

[image]

If those lines at the bottom are equal to the line at the side, does that mean the angles at the top are equal.  Hint 1: the first angle is 45 degrees.  Can the angles all be $45$ degrees?  Hint 2:  I can add equal lines forever.  Can I add equal angles forever?

And another image.

[image]

Here the angles are both $30^\circ$.  But because this is a $30-60-90$ triangle and a smaller $30-60-90$ triangle we can actually calculate all the sides.

You can see they are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

AD is not necessarily equal to DB. They are only equal if a = b. This is because when a side of a triangle is cut into two pieces by an angle bisector, the ratio of the 2 segments is the same as the ratio of the 2 sides.